# If I extend a word, do I get points for all the words, or just the straight line word?

Tags: scrabble

I'm having an argument that will determine the winner

Board looks like this:

```
S
AB
DE
 N
 D
```

If you add E to get:

```
S
AB
DE
EN
 D
```

Do you get points for just SADE and EN, or do you get AB and DE as well?
I think you only get points for the straight line word you extend, but I can't find a rule that says so.

Comment: Downvoters: please refrain from voting down legitimate, well-posed questions that fit within the scope of "on-topic" for this SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct (you get points just for SADE and EN, not for the other words still on the board that were on the board before your turn). Here's the rule from the [official rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) (emphasis added):

> The score for each turn is the sum of the letter values in each word(s) **formed or modified** on that turn

Perhaps an even easier way to resolve this doesn't even involve going back to the rules and finding the legal code that specifies it one way ot the other, but to consider what the ramifications of the other way of doing things would be.

Change your example a bit and the answer becomes clear:

If you add your `E` to

```
S
ABOUT
DENTISTRY
 N
 D
```

to make `SADE` and `EN` again:

```
S
ABOUT
DENTISTRY
EN
 D
```

would you attempt to score `ABOUT` and `DENTISTRY`? I think not.

Comment: Note that if you played that E onto a double- or triple-word square, all of SADE and EN get doubled or tripled. This is because you covered that square on your current turn. However, you don't score any premiums coming from the squares that got covered by SAD or N in previous turns.